# Error: fetching abi for <accountname>: Read past end of buffer

Tags: eosjs

I am trying to send transaction but getting this error

Error: fetching abi for : Read past end of buffer

Comment: Maybe you could add some more details. E.g. Versions of your software and which tool/framework you are using.

Comment: I've also got this error message when testing on Jungle testnet. When I updated my contract, it disappeared.

Comment: I was trying to trasfer EOS tokens but getting this error how to get rid of it using jungle network with eosjs 20.0.0

Answer (score 1):

we have an example format transaction

```
        const transaction = {
        actions: [{
            **account**,
            name: action,
            authorization: [{
                actor,
                permission
            }],
            data
        }]
    }
```

Because you put wrong **account**.

**account** is that owner contract that has action. action can be found in **account** contract, So it generates that error